# Running cmd command from vb.net issue

Tags: wpf, vb.net, shell, cmd, processstartinfo

I am trying to run the following code in a click event. However because it executes the command in the cmd shell, I don't know why it wont run. What I can do is open cmd.exe as Administrator by commenting out the Arguments. As well as stick these arguments in a .bat file, then running from process.start.

However, why I cant run the shell with the arguments? I'd prefer this method over putting the arguments in a .bat file.

```
    Dim process As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
        Dim startInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
        ' startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden

        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
        If System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then ' Windows Vista or higher
            startInfo.Verb = "runas"
        Else
            ' No need to prompt to run as admin
        End If
        startInfo.Arguments = "/C bcdedit /set {current} safeboot network"
        process.StartInfo = startInfo
        process.Start()
```

Comment: Try using the full file path to `cmd.exe`.

Comment: So startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe /C bcdedit /set {current} safeboot network" ?

Comment: Try to change the /C in /K to see if there is any error message

Comment: Is `cmd.exe` in your `bin` directory? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @ Steve /K worked but it opened cmd.exe from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe . It mention that bcdedit was not a recongized command. hmm why wouldn't it open cmd.exe program in %windir%\system32\cmd.exe instead?

Comment: @ Sheridan. No I thought it would be automatically called from %windir%\system32

Comment: becuase I need to run bcdedit, it looks like I need to start %windir%\system32\cmd.exe, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to copy bcdedit.exe to my project. I had thought that calling cmd.exe would go to the location bcdedit.exe was located.